# How to delete text not matching regex in phpStorm

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, phpstorm, transform

Having a JSON logfile, I want to extract the product IDs to have a clean list:

```
{"comment": "comment.", "product":"100"}
{"comment": "comment.", "product":"555"}
{"comment": "comment.", "product":"100"}
{"comment": "comment.", "product":"99999"}
```

To

```
100
555
100
99999
```

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 0):

**How I thought I'd do it:**

1. Search for all products: `product\":\"(\d+)\"`
2. Click the button in the search form `Select All Occurrences`
3. Select "invert selection" from Edit menu, which doesn't exist unfortunately.

**How I endet up doing it:**

1. Search for everything before the string I want to keep: `\{(.*)product\":\"` and remove these
2. Search for trailing `"}` and remove those

**How I did it in Notepad++:**

1. Search for regex with negating ("not matching"): [Find lines not starting with " in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164518/find-lines-not-starting-with-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

As you are considering Notepad++ in your answer, here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\d\r\n]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\d\r\n]+      # 1 or more any character that is not a digit or a linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]